# is Android SDK Manager downloader not capable of resume support?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to update Android SDK Tools 25.1.1 to 25.1.3 using Android SDK Manager under wind7x64. Size of download: 219.5MiB, Bytes Received: 600MiB, 
Log: read time out, try: 6 times, it seems it is not capable of resume support.
Any workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience Android SDK Manager is frequently incapable of resuming downloads if there are networks hiccups. You could manually download the SDK Tools version 25.1.3 from this link:

For windows
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.1.3-windows.zip

You could use, if you need it, [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) which is an Open Source download manager that can pause/resume http downloads.

Once you manage to manually download the file, unzip it in you SDK directory: the "tools" folder will be replaced with the new content of the archive. Make sure though that any related software to the SDK (Android Studio and the SDK Manager itself) are closed before proceeding.